# mypy not picking up installed stubs

Tags: python, mypy

I've installed boto3, boto3-stubs, and mypy:

Pipfile:

```
"boto3" = "*"
boto3-stubs = {extras = ["ec2", "s3"], version = "*"}
mypy = "*"
```

But running `mypy .` gives the error:

```
error: Skipping analyzing 'boto3': found module but no type hints or library stubs
```

Do I need to configure something for mypy to find the stubs?

I'm using python 3.8.6, mypy 0.790, boto3 1.16.59, boto3-stubs 1.16.59 all installed in a virtual env.

Comment: Did you solve this ? I am getting same error and couldn't solve it

Answer (score 4):

Install [boto3 stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/):

```
python3 -m pip install boto3-stubs
```

Comment: OP wrote that they installed this already.

Comment: I had this same issue and `pip install boto3-stubs` worked for me.
It resolved the same error with `from botocore.exceptions import ClientError`

Answer (score 2):

I used venv and I got it to work using the following steps:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install mypy 'boto3-stubs[ec2,s3]'
venv/bin/mypy .
```

[mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) [boto3 stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/)

If you're using VSCode then select the right interpreter using: Python: Select interpreter
I use venv so I pointed to `./venv/bin/python`